# Does laravel User.php ORM have to extend Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User? Can functionality be brought in via a trait?

Tags: laravel, authentication, orm

Out of the box, laravel 5.2 comes with a couple of ORM classes. Most notably, one of these is the User ORM class. Most ORM models, must extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, which looks something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Articles extends Model {
...
```

However, the user model must extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`, if you want to use any of the authentication features. This is typically seen as something like the following:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable {
...
```

However, all of my ORM files extend a custom ORM class, (which contains some default query scoping methods and other very useful things I've written) which then, in turn extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.

So in other words, I want to have:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
App\Klass\OrmRoot\MyCoolSubClass extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
App\Klass\Orm\User extends MyCoolSubClass
```

But I'm forced to have:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
App\Klass\OrmRoot\MyCoolSubClass extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
App\Klass\Orm\User extends Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User
```

As PHP doesn't support polymorhpic inheritance, when stating which class my User.php ORM file extends from, I have to choose between either duplicating all the methods I have in my custom base ORM class inside the User ORM class (ridiculous), or not having the user ORM class have user authentication functionality. Both seem unfeasible.

Is there any other way to include the Authenticable functionality in a User.php ORM file? Perhaps as a trait? There doesn't seem to be any documentation regarding this usage pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just figured it out.
Checking the content of `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`, revealed it to contain only the following:

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
}
```

Having my User.php ORM file extend my custom class "MyCoolSubClass", and ensuring that it also implements all traits and contracts shown above achieves the desired result of being able to use the features of my custom ORM base class along with the auth features.